# No instance of function template matches the specified type

Tags: c++, templates

I've read that could be a issue of IntelliSense, but I really don't know is it true or not.
When I compile the code, I get an error (title) and don't know how to fix it. My book (Stephen Prata's "Sams C++ Primer Plus") doesn't answer to my problem. I've wrote a pretty similar program and the problem didn't appear.

Maybe the problem is in type specifier? Has it be the same as template's one? REALLY sorry for my language...

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T maxn(T tab[], int size);

template <> float maxn<float>(float, int); // Problem appears here...

int main()
{
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T maxn(T tab[], int size)
{
    T max = tab[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] > max) max = tab[i];
    }
}
```

I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Please at least post the error you're getting. Can you also post the part of the other program that did work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of the specialization is incorrect.  You give `float` but according to the template it should be an array of floats.

```
template <> float maxn<float>(float[], int);
//                                 ^
// You need to indicate that the first parameter is an array.
```

Note that you do not declare a body for the specialization, so linking will fail if you attempt to use it.  (Unless you are providing an implementation in another compilation unit.)

Comment: Oh... So specialization has to has the same set of parameters as template. Thank you!

(I don't have the specialization's body, 'cause I've interrupted writing, when the error occured)

Comment: @Seu Yes, otherwise you are not specializing the template, you're just providing an overload -- which is fine, it just would not be a template specialization.  (`float maxn(float, int);` would be valid.)